# `yum`/`dnf`/`rpm` equivalent to `dpkg -l` for RHEL/CentOS?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, rpm

Is there an equivalent `yum`, `dnf`, or `rpm` command to Debian/Ubuntu's `dpkg -l` command to list *both* package names and installation status?

Comment: That would be an _enormous_ list. It's very unlikely that you need the entire list. What exactly _do_ you intend to do? yum/dnf have some more useful options for getting at the information you want, if you can specify what that information is.

Comment: I want it to output the information for a particular package, like @Koffee 's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum list packagename
```

this will return a list of installed packages, then a list of available/not installed

For example

```
[root@RHELPOC ~]# yum list systemd
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 1:42:23 ago on Fri 08 Jan 2021 16:47:42 GMT.
Installed Packages
systemd.x86_64              239-41.el8_3                @rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
Available Packages
systemd.i686                239-41.el8_3.1              rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
systemd.x86_64              239-41.el8_3.1              rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
```

Comment: Be aware that the `@` symbol in front of the repository name means the package is installed. Also `yum info <package>` will give much more detail about the package.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -l` is equivalent to `rpm -qa`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: sorry, option got lost, now it is added.
dpkg and rpm are on the same level (package installation tools: install/remove/update)
apt and yum are on same level (package repository management, download, ...)
sorry, BR chris

Comment: I see. I'll edit your post for grammar, then.

Answer (score 0):

`yum list installed` or `dnf list installed` should print a list of all installed packages as well as their source repo and version.

You could pipe it into `yum info` for more details: `yum list installed | xargs yum info`, but this will be quite a list !

Comment: Yeah, I would need to pipe it through grep, then.